# When a stored email & pasword is selected in EditText, the text in all buttons changes to the selected email

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I've no clue why this is happening. In my app, when I login successfully, I'm prompted **Save password to Google**. After selected save and logging out, when i click in the email field, I'm prompted to login with saved email & password. If I do so, then the text of all of my activity's buttons changes to the email I've selected.

[image]
[image]
**EDIT: I did some digging, and found that it's caused by setting             android:inputType="textMultiLine" on the button.
**

Answer (score 0):

So, after some digging(which i should've done before asking the question), i found that this undesired behavior was caused because I had set inputType to textMultiline in my button style.

Setting inputType to none solves the problem.